# how to specify photo type with Facebook PHP API

Tags: php, facebook

I'm new to php and facebook and I'm trying to specify that I only want album photos back in a small type.
I'm sure once I see how to do this it will be very easy but I just can work out how to send arguments with my request.
This is what I'm working with:

```
// get albums
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
foreach($albums['data'] as $album)
{
    // get all photos for album
    $photos = $facebook->api("/{$album['id']}/photos");

    foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
    {
        echo "<img src='{$photo['source']}' />", "<br />";
    }
}
```

How do I send that I want type=small

```
$photos = $facebook->api("/{$album['id']}/photos?type=small");
```

This isn't working

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// get session object which returns an array that contains [session_key], [uid], [expires], [secret], [base_domain], [access_token], and [sig]
```

$session = $facebook->getSession();

// so what we want from our session would be the access_tokken for us to get the photos.
and we would do this to get the photos that are of type = small

$photos = $facebook->api("/".$album['id']."/photos?access_tokken=".$session['access_token']."&type=small");

Comment: thank for your reply. The first block of code is returning the large photos but I only want small. I think the access token is already working. Reading some more it looks like I need to be sending type=thumbnail for photos (i.e. not profile pics) but this still isn't working for me.

Comment: this worked but I needed to change the foreach loop to get the 'picture' value. - thanks for your help. So basically if you want to send arguments you need to manually send the access_token? (that would otherwise be taken care of?)